# Как получить доступ к текущей громкости iPhone и отобразить ее в своем приложении на swift?

Tags: swift

Возможно ли, разрабатывая приложения на swift под iOS, получить доступ к текущему уровню громкости телефона и отобразить его в плеере?
Пока я использую вариант в AVPlayer:

```
@IBAction func handleVolumeChange(_ sender: UISlider) {
        player.volume = sender.value
    }
```

с предустановленным уровнем параметра maximum UISlider, в моем случае 1, двигая бегунок слайдера все работает и громкость изменяется, но начальная громкость стоит 1, а не текущая громкость воспроизведения аудио самого iPhone. Если включить системное приложения Музыка или Подкасты, там всегда уровень слайдера громкости соответсвует текущему уровню громкости воспроизведения аудио самого iPhone.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете узнать системную громкость так:

```
var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if ((try? session.setActive(true)) != nil) {
        volumeChange.setValue(session.outputVolume, animated: true)
        print("initial volume = \(session.outputVolume)")
    }
}
```

Или использовать MPVolumeView

> из документации по AVPlayer.volume
>
> Значение 0 означает молчание; значение 1.0 (по умолчанию) указывает полный объем звука для экземпляра проигрывателя.
>
> Это свойство используется для управления громкостью звука проигрывателя относительно громкости системы. Программного способа управления системным уровнем громкости в iOS нет, но вы можете использовать класс MPVolumeView среды MediaPlayer для представления стандартного пользовательского интерфейса для управления уровнем звука.

Comment: flowGlen, спасибо за ответ